# Notify and Wait in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

i have a problem with notify() and wait().
I want my main thread to be able to force other thread to wait and notify whenever i want to.
It seems i dont understand everything because notify doesnt work. I cant acces my NOTIFY method.

Here is my code:

MAIN THREAD:

```
public class troll {

    static Runnable R0;
    static Thread TH;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("TROLOLOLL0");
        watek R0 = new watek();
        Thread TH = new Thread(R0);

        synchronized(TH){
            TH.start();
            R0.NOTIFY();
            }

    }

}
```

My THREAD Class:

```
public class watek implements Runnable {

    public watek(){

    }

    public  void run() {


        System.out.print("STOP");
            this.WAIT();
            System.out.print("Running again");

    }


    public synchronized void WAIT(){
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   

    public  void NOTIFY(){
        notify();

    }   
}
```

Comment: The `NOTIFY` method is defined in class `watek`, but you are tring to call it on a `Thread` object. Call it on your `watek` object instead: `R0.NOTIFY()` instead of `TH.NOTIFY()`.

Comment: done, but now wait() is taking forever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a race. The call to `NOTIFY` in the `main` method might happen before the `wait` in the new thread. There would then be nothing left to wake it up.

Comment: @user3402584, [What he said,...] because foo.notify() does not do _anything at all_ if some other thread is not already waiting in foo.wait().  The object, foo, does not remember that it was notified.

Answer (score 1):

synchronize your NOTIFY method. Also use watek.NOTIFY() instead of TH.NOTIFY().

Comment: Why is synchronizing the method necessary? They've already locked the monitor in the main method.

Comment: Before using wait/notify/notifyAll you need to own target object's monitor (here your target is watek).

Comment: Ah, I thought they had `synchronized(RO)`.